# ejabberd creating private groups

Tags: ejabberd

Need to develop an application that will be multi company, each company must have a group of people (employees) which you can participate in sub groups which such an organizational hierarchy.
     It is possible to create, in ejabberd, a structure as described above, to allow the development of a communication application in real time, without individuals of different companies to exchange each other post?

I look forward considerations.

Answer (score 0):

ejabberd support virtual hosting and groupchat (MUC). It seems to be what you need, from what you describe.